# create fingerprint device and push token pushbullet

Tags: android, pushbullet

As Pushbullet API says here https://docs.pushbullet.com/#create-device

> String fingerprint for the device, used by apps to avoid duplicate devices. Value is platform-specific.
>   Example: "nLN19IRNzS5xidPF+X8mKGNRpQo2X6XBgyO30FL6OiQ="

`fingerprint` tag is used by apps (I' m creating an alternative one for android) to avoid duplicate devices. This value, as stated above is **platform-specific**.

What I kindly ask, to you all, and hopefully to Pushbullet staff, is how to generate a `fingerprint` avoiding to re-create same device.

Same help is appreciated on how to get `push_token`

> push_token string  Platform-specific push token. Normally a prefix followed by an identifier. Prefixes are set per-app, if you want to receive push notifications in your app, contact api@pushbullet.com with your push backend credentials to get a prefix.
>   Example: "production:f73be0ee7877c8c7fa69b1468cde764f"

Thanks in advance.